# Rasch: Desicion for model and group-analysis

Tags: r

I currently have a data set of about 300 people on behaviors (answers: yes/no/NA) + variables on age, place of residence (city/country), income, etc.

In principle, I would like to find out the item difficulties for the overall sample (with which R-package is the best?-How does that work? Don't fully understand some codes :/)

and in the next step examine different groups (young, old, city/country, income (median split) with regard to their possibly significantly different item difficulties.

How do I do that? (is this possible with Wald tests, Rasch trees, or raschmix?) (do I need latent groups - which are grouped data-driven)?

Comment: Please show us what you have coded or tired so far.

Comment: I suggest moving the question to [stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com). Still, even there no one would answer which is the "best R-package". However, try some of the packages mentioned in the [psychometrics task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Psychometrics.html); e.g. eRm, ltm, mirt and TAM. For the second part: the theory you are looking for seems to be _differential item functioning_. Look in the manuals of TAM and mirt or in the aforementioned taskview for the keyword **DIF**.

Comment: I run now the first steps of the eRm package and got a item and person estimate + i wanted to run some model tests but often with different criteria the Andersen's Likelihood Ratio test took like 3 hours to run... is this normal??? and brougth often results as the following: with mean-split: Andersen LR-test: 
#LR-value: 254 
#Chi-square df: 95 
#p-value:  0 --> what does this tell me?? especially is 0 even possible? for mean was: #Andersen LR-test: 
#LR-value: 85.1 
#Chi-square df: 91 
#p-value:  0.653